# Fullcalendar momentTimezonePlugin cause error

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-5, moment-timezone

I'm using the latest version of Fullcalendar and i want to change the nowIndicator by timezone, so i've found the plugin MomentTimezone

When i added the plugin to the list of plugins in calendar options :

```
plugins: [ momentTimezonePlugin, timeGridPlugin ],
```

I got this error in momentTimezonePlugin :

```
Property 'eventResizeJoinTransforms' is missing in type 'import("c:/Workspace/Monitoring/monitoring-ui/src/main/webapp/app/node_modules/@fullcalendar/moment-timezone/node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main").PluginDef' but required in type 'import("c:/Workspace/Monitoring/monitoring-ui/src/main/webapp/app/node_modules/@fullcalendar/common/main").PluginDef'.ts(2741)
main.d.ts(938, 5): 'eventResizeJoinTransforms' is declared here.
```

here is the different version of librairies :

```
"@fullcalendar/angular": "5.5.0",
"@fullcalendar/core": "5.5.1",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.5.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.5.0",
"@fullcalendar/list": "5.5.0",
"@fullcalendar/moment-timezone": "5.8.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.5.1",
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? Since 9 they've added dedicated component https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular Did you try it out?

Comment: In the project, the version is Angular 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned using Angular 8. I'm afraid you need to either downgrade your FullCalendar package version or upgrade Angular to version 9 if you want to avoid weird issues using FullCalendar with Angular.

**Supported Angular Versions**

```
@fullcalendar/angular version 5 supports Angular 9 - 11.
```

source: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular

Comment: I've resolved it by using the same version of timezone and fullcalendar (5.5.0)

Comment: Glad you've solved your issue! Although I'd recommend updating your Angular version to stay up to date and get benefit of new features

Comment: I hope to do it but it's very big project, the migration is very long and it cost